# Comparing two things: a Cells.Value and integer but Type Mismatch error.

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in Column 6. The data here is "differences" and is calculated as the difference between the previous two columns. The values in the difference column should be 0 since I am doing a reconciliation.

What happens is that there is a for loop where I go row by row to check if the value in Column 6 is equal to 0. If the value is 0, then I am good. I need to know if it is not 0 so I do a further investigation.

```
 'calculating the differences in previous cols
          MyReport.Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=RC[-4]-RC[-2]"
'This is where the Type error occurs at .value<>0 line 
If MyReport.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Value <> 0 Then
                    MyReport.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
                End If
```

The numbers are in long not integer, maybe that's why? I used to have it in integer and it worked but I have a larger data set so I need to use long. Using long gave me this error where I didn't have it before.

Comment: try <>"0" they may be text???

Comment: My guess is that one or more of your formulas, `"=RC[-4]-RC[-2]"`, result in an error.  You need to look at the data and see why the return is an error, or check if it is  an error before trying to equate it to something.

Comment: You have text in a cell that does not like  being compared to zero. If the text is not supposed to be there, fix it. If it is supposed to be there then you can use a sum wrapper as a safety or check with IsNumeric. e.g. `If application.Sum(MyReport.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Value) <> 0 Then`. Why aren't you using Conditional Formatting for this?

Comment: Yes..I realized what is causing the error. The information in one of the columns is from a VLOOKUP and some of them have a  #N/A, thus the difference row would have a #N/A and excel does not like comparing #N/A to the number 0. 

My goal is to look through the column and highlight the ones that are either #N/A or non 0 values. 

@Jeeped This is a small part of a big macro, everything else works except this is small part which is not allowing my macro to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to do it, in case other people also have the same problem.

```
For Row=2 to RowCounter 
    If IsNumeric(MyReport.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Value) = True Then
        If MyReport.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Value <> 0 Then
        My.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        End If
    ElseIf IsNumeric(MyReport.Cells(LastRow, 6).Value) = False Then
    MyReport.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
    End If
```

Only if the data in the cell is a number, then will I check if it's not equal to 0. If it is not a number (IsNumeric=False) then I will automatically highlight it.